# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Debugging Built-In Pipeline

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, middleware

Thanks to the extensive ASP.NET Core documentation, we know what is happening at high-level but I also want to dive deep to understand what is **exactly** happening while built-in middlewares are executing in a debugging session.

I can, of course, enable source linking and source stepping to further continue stepping over the framework code but **only if** starting from a breakpoint available on my side.

Hence, I was wondering if there is a straightforward way to fully step over all the framework code about the executed middleware components. For example; debugging `UseRouting()` step by step from the beginning or `UseAuthentication()` and etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/docs/BuildFromSource.md may be helpful